# Which of the following demonstrates the pattern of development in Greylag Geese?

Tags: zoology, ethology, ornithology

[image]

Which of the following demonstrates the pattern of development in Greylag Geese? {Please give specific answers, which among the following gives the best available demonstration?, If needed, have a look at the Paragraph (Image Embedded)}

(A) Geese reared by humans cannot be taught to respond to its own species.

(B) The hatching at an advanced stage is critical for imprinting.

(C) The capacity to recognize an adult of its own species is necessarily inherited.

(D) Rearing by humans does not alter the object of the behavioral routine.

Option A: “Geese reared by humans cannot be taught to respond to its own species” is correct.
This is inferred from the 4th paragraph 2nd line: “When young geese are reared wholly by human beings it is towards humans that the young geese direct their behavioural routines”. This line clearly states that geese wholly reared by humans respond only towards humans. Also from the 2nd Paragraph 3rd line It is clear. 
Option B: “The hatching at an advanced stage is critical for imprinting” is false.
Hatching at an advanced Stage is not shown by Greylag Geese, it is shown by Godwits. (3rd Paragraph, 1st & 2nd Line: The young of Godwits hatch at an advanced stage of development and soon after hatching can recognize the adult bird.) (So the fact is not conclusive from Behavioural Pattern of Greylag Geese) Imprinting can be shown by Greylag Geese, which do not have a prolonged period of hatching, and imprinting totally depends on whatever creature happens to be present at the right moment in their development. 
Options C: “The capacity to recognise an adult of its own species is necessarily inherited” is false. According to the 2nd Paragraph, 2nd line: The capacities to recognise the right stimulus are not always inherited. 
Option D: “Rearing by Humans does not alter the object of the behavioural routine.” is false, as shown in 4th Paragraph 2nd & 3rd line: When young geese are reared wholly by human beings it is towards humans that the young geese direct their behavioural routines.
Hence, answer should be A.

So Am I correct?

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic unless you show some effort solving them.

Comment: Mr Chris, This isn't a Home-work Question! It is an exam question, I have already answered it in the Paper, I want to know from Experts what should be correct! & Please If you are unable to answer don't comment the things you don't know!
I hope you Understand.
DWITI

Comment: Still: How about adding your answer? And I comment on everything I want.

Comment: Ok I am adding my logic, (Option wise)
Option A: “Geese reared by humans cannot be taught to respond to its own species” is correct.
This is inferred from the 4th paragraph 2nd line: “When young geese are reared wholly by human beings it is towards humans that the young geese direct their behavioural routines”. This line clearly states that geese wholly reared by humans respond only towards humans. Also from the 2nd Paragraph 3rd line It is clear.

Comment: Option B: “The hatching at an advanced stage is critical for imprinting” is false.
Hatching at an advanced Stage is not shown by Greylag Geese, it is shown by Godwits. (3rd Paragraph, 1st & 2nd Line: The young of Godwits hatch at an advanced stage of development and soon after hatching can recognize the adult bird.) [So the fact is not conclusive from Behavioural Pattern of Greylag Geese]
Imprinting can be shown by Greylag Geese, which do not have a prolonged period of hatching, and imprinting totally depends on whatever creature happens to be present at the right moment in their development.

Comment: Options C: “The capacity to recognise an adult of its own species is necessarily inherited” is false.
According to the 2nd Paragraph, 2nd line: The capacities to recognise the right stimulus are not always inherited. 

Option D: “Rearing by Humans does not alter the object of the behavioural routine.” is false, as shown in 4th Paragraph 2nd & 3rd line: When young geese are reared wholly by human beings it is towards humans that the young geese direct their behavioural routines.
Hence, answer should be A. (Therefore, It is not B) {Actually the examiners say that It is B SO I need expert's help}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems fine to me..

Option B: The hatching at an advanced stage is critical for imprinting.

This is wrong because [Konrad Lorenz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konrad_Lorenz) (who rediscovered imprinting)

> demonstrated how incubator-hatched geese would imprint on the first
>   suitable moving stimulus they saw within what he called a "critical
>   period" between 13–16 hours shortly after hatching ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imprinting_%28psychology%29)).

So saying that the hatchling should be at an advanced stage is incorrect.

Option C: The capacity to recognize an adult of its own species is necessarily inherited.

Again this is incorrect because Lorenz has also stated that

> The human-imprinted gosling will unequivocally refuse to follow a
>   goose instead of a human, but it will not differentiate between a
>   petite, slender young girl and a big old man with a beard (Lorenz,
>   1965) ([reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Applied_History_of_Psychology/Attachment)).

Also in [this article](http://www.starlingcentral.net/keeping_a_starling.htm) it is implied that starlings that are imprinted to humans do not relate to its own kind.

Option D: Rearing by humans does not alter the object of the behavioral routine.

From the earlier findings, this is obviously false. Moreover a duck keeper has explained imprinting thus:

> An imprinted duck--a duck that was raised from the moment of hatching
>   by a human and so views the human caretaker as a parent or equal--may
>   become accustomed to riding in the car. Imprinted ducks might go
>   camping with you (although you must keep them beside you at all times
>   or in a crate) or go on play dates to a friend's house (you will not
>   want to take them to a farm or a public pond where they may contract
>   diseases). If your duck is in a diaper, you will need to change the
>   diaper every hour or so ([reference](http://shantiperez.hubpages.com/hub/Keeping-Pet-Ducks-and-Geese)).

This shows clear behaviour changes.

Option A:  Geese reared by humans cannot be taught to respond to its own species.

It is mostly accepted that it is not with Lorenz himself stating that

> imprinting is irreversible. It is essential in learning that what has
>   been learned can be either forgotten or modified ([reference](http://www.muskingum.edu/~psych/psycweb/history/lorenz.htm)).

However there are claims to the contrary nowadays with it now firmly established that filial and sexual preferences are reversible ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1801945)). [Another interesting article](http://www.apa.org/monitor/2011/12/imprinting.aspx) by the American Psychological Association with a few links you might want to check out.

In conclusion, Option A could also have its problems with some response to its species possible, but overall it is the most and best plausible answer.

[image]

Dr Lorenz with his imprinted geese. Also a very interesting read ([reference](http://www.cerebromente.org.br/n14/experimento/lorenz/index-lorenz.html))

Comment: See I need to claim for this, because The answer given by the question setter is B (Which according to you & me is wrong), So I am using your answer as Reference for my claim apart from my explanation!
So Permission Needed!

Comment: Help urself to it. if ur claim works toh bata dena

Comment: Ya Ya, I will tell you (How can I contact you, any e-mail or Fb account?)

Comment: This is pretty much an open forum. My answers are not copyrighted and it is very much open to change or dispute. I personally have no problems with my answers being used for any educational purpose

Comment: Buddy, according to you, B is never possible, Isn't it?

Comment: From references, lorenz used to imprint between the time period I mentioned. There are also articles that peg the best time for imprinting between 24 and 48 hours. I wouldn't call that an advanced stage. I would be very interested in his references and proof if he decided to refute what I have pointed out in the article.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15286/discussion-between-the-last-word-and-dwiti-k-das).